# Julia: how do you list kernels installed with `installkernel`?

Tags: julia, ijulia-notebook

Is there a built-in IJulia function that list the kernels I have installed? I installed a kernel using `installkernel` and some time after I wanted to remove it with `rm`. I could remember the name I gave it but not the path IJulia uses to install the kernels, so I had to manually search my system.

It would be handy if IJulia could list the names and/or paths and I'm surprised that I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IJulia.kerneldir()` to get the directory holding kernels.
Then if you do e.g. `readdir(IJulia.kerneldir(), join=true)` you get a vector of directory names that can be used in `rm`.

Comment: In julia 1.2 I get the following error `function readdir does not accept keyword arguments" :/ funny that this is so involved, I wonder if this sould be made a part of IJulia's API

Comment: It has been added in Julia 1.4. Then use `joinpath.(IJulia.kerneldir(), readdir(IJulia.kerneldir()))`. The `join=true` only makes sure that you get a full path and not a list of names within the directory.